# Why do I get a contention error for a simple combination circuit in CircuitVerse?

Tags: digital-logic, simulation

I created a [simple circuit on CircuitVerse](https://circuitverse.org/users/28963/projects/115344):

[image: schematic diagram]

When I change the `C` input from 0 to 1, I get a `Contention Error`.

[image: animated gif]

What does the error mean, and what is wrong with my circuit?

How can I fix it?

Comment: This question is best served in circuit verse fourms, also you have connected to terminals together with a wire

Comment: @VoltageSpike I didn't see a CircuitVerse forum, but I see now that there is a Discord. Thanks for helping me even though I posted in the wrong place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you have connected two terminals together with a wire, delete the and gate correct the wire and add in the and gate again

Answer (score 1):

Although the chosen answer seems to be the correct one in this case, I'm adding one more possibility that gives a similar error, since this result is one of the top ones on Google. There could actually be two 'NOT' gates, one stacked on top of each other. Then it'd give a ContentionError.